# How do I filter data by timestamp one day backward

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Here's my filter criteria (one day backward), called this `df`

```
customer_id   timestamp
1             2018-06-03 17:56:52
2             2018-06-03 18:42:51
```

Here's the main dataset, called this `df2`

```
transaction_id customer_id   timestamp
1              1             2018-06-02 09:56:23
2              1             2018-06-03 02:56:52
3              1             2018-06-03 12:56:52
4              2             2018-06-03 12:40:51
5              2             2018-06-03 18:40:51
6              2             2018-06-03 18:48:50
```

What I want is

```
transaction_id customer_id   timestamp
2              1             2018-06-03 02:56:52
3              1             2018-06-03 12:56:52
4              2             2018-06-03 12:40:51
5              2             2018-06-03 18:40:51
```

This because for `customer_id = 1` the filter criteria should be start from `2018-06-02 17:56:52` to `2018-06-03 17:56:52`

and

This because for `customer_id = 2` the filter criteria should be start from `2018-06-02 18:42:51` to `2018-06-03 18:42:51`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) by `Series` created by `map` with another by subtracted by one day, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df2['customer_id'].map(df1.set_index('customer_id')['timestamp'])

df = df2[df2['timestamp'].between(s - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'), s)]
print (df)
   transaction_id  customer_id           timestamp
1               2            1 2018-06-03 02:56:52
2               3            1 2018-06-03 12:56:52
3               4            2 2018-06-03 12:40:51
4               5            2 2018-06-03 18:40:51
```

**Detail**:

```
print (s)
0   2018-06-03 17:56:52
1   2018-06-03 17:56:52
2   2018-06-03 17:56:52
3   2018-06-03 18:42:51
4   2018-06-03 18:42:51
5   2018-06-03 18:42:51
Name: customer_id, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create new time and then check if timestamp lies between the time i,e

```
after = df2['customer_id'].map(df1.set_index('customer_id')['timestamp'])
before = after - pd.Timedelta('1 days')


df2[(df2['timestamp'] > before) & (df2['timestamp'] < after)]

   transaction_id  customer_id           timestamp
1               2            1 2018-06-03 02:56:52
2               3            1 2018-06-03 12:56:52
3               4            2 2018-06-03 12:40:51
4               5            2 2018-06-03 18:40:51
```